# Sonicwall SSO with NPS

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, nps

I have a SonicWall where I want to enable the RADIUS SSO capability. [The article for doing this](https://support.software.dell.com/sonicwall-e-class-nsa-series/kb/sw11075) states the RADIUS server `Send the user’s IP address in either Framed-IP-Address or Calling-Station-Id attribute in both Start and Stop messages.`

My setup is as follows:
`AP -> NPS -> (RADIUS Accounting forwarded) Sonicwall`

When connecting to the AP, it successfully logs in. When the forwarded event reaches the SonicWall, it does not have the `Framed-IP-Address` or the IP in the `Calling-Station-Id` (only MAC address).

```
 Attribute Value Pairs
    AVP: l=19  t=Acct-Session-Id(44): 53AB6162-00000010
    AVP: l=6  t=Acct-Status-Type(40): Stop(2)
    AVP: l=6  t=Acct-Authentic(45): RADIUS(1)
    AVP: l=10  t=User-Name(1): user
    AVP: l=6  t=NAS-IP-Address(4): 10.10.0.150
    AVP: l=14  t=NAS-Identifier(32): xxxxxxxxx
    AVP: l=6  t=NAS-Port(5): 0
    AVP: l=35  t=Called-Station-Id(30): XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX:SSID
    AVP: l=19  t=Calling-Station-Id(31): XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
    AVP: l=6  t=NAS-Port-Type(61): Wireless-802.11(19)
    AVP: l=23  t=Connect-Info(77): CONNECT 0Mbps 802.11b
    AVP: l=46  t=Class(25): 420e04e70000013700011700000000000000000000000000...
    AVP: l=6  t=Acct-Session-Time(46): 604
    AVP: l=6  t=Acct-Input-Packets(47): 182
    AVP: l=6  t=Acct-Output-Packets(48): 145
    AVP: l=6  t=Acct-Input-Octets(42): 32797
    AVP: l=6  t=Acct-Output-Octets(43): 47272
    AVP: l=6  t=Event-Timestamp(55): Jun 26, 2014 09:47:54.000000000 PDT
    AVP: l=6  t=Acct-Terminate-Cause(49): User-Request(1)
    AVP: l=22  t=Proxy-State(33): 1700000000000000000000000000000000000039
```

I found out that my Ubiquiti APs do not send the `Framed-IP-Address` or the IP in the `Calling-Station-Id` and they recommend the RADIUS to get this information from the DHCP. I must be missing something as I cannot find the configuration anywhere in the NPS or the DHCP service.

How do I get the correct information to my SonicWall through DHCP or NPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other people have [asked Ubiquiti for the same thing](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Feature-Requests/Include-RADIUS-attribute-Framed-IP-Address-in-accounting-request/idi-p/591089) to no avail. It looks, after examining the code, that it would take some reasonable engineering to make that happen. ([Ubiquiti came to the same conclusion](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/airOS-Software-Configuration/WPA-Auth-EAP-with-radius-AAA-Framed-IP-Address/td-p/123524).)

The Ubiquiti APs are Linux-based and use [hostapd](http://hostap.epitest.fi/hostapd/) to provide their AP functionality. I dug into the source for hostapd a little bit, and am not finding that it supports populating the `Framed-IP-Address` RADIUS attribute (`src/radius/radius.c`, the `radius_attr_type radius_attrs` struct). As far as populating the `Calling-Station-Id` attribute, hostpad only populates that with the MAC address, from what I can see (`src/ap/ieee802_11_auth.c` in the function `hostapd_radius_acl_query` where it gets the MAC from `hostapd_allowed_address`, and in `src/ap/ieee802_1x.c` in the function `add_common_radius_sta_attr`).

Since hostapd is concerned primarily with authenticating the mobile unit (MU) (and a *little* bit of RADIUS accounting) and isn't handling arbitrary IP traffic for the MU once it's authenticated it's not really going to have the IP of the MU to give to RADIUS.

I don't think you're going to get what you want w/o writing code. In theory, you could stick some kind of layer 7 RADIUS proxy between the NPS service and the Sonicwall and re-write that attribute from the MAC to the IP address (querying against your DHCP servers). FreeRADIUS [policies](http://freeradius.org/features/policy.html) might just be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Following Evan's suggestion. I ended up writing my own code using the [unifi-api](https://github.com/calmh/unifi-api) by calmh. [My fork of the project](https://github.com/andrewwippler/unifi-api) includes instructions on how to set it up with FreeRADIUS.

I went the FreeRADIUS > NPS (Auth) > Sonicwall (Acct) route.